# Sorting DataTables RowGroup

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I'm using the jQuery DataTables plugin. I'd like to create a Datatables rowgroup by column1 and sorting single groups by column2. However when I sort column2, rowgroup doesn't work

```js
var table = $('#DT_StatMov').DataTable({
  "ajax": {
    "url": url,
    "type": "POST",
    "datatype": "json"
  },
  "columns": [{
    "data": "Name"
  }, {
    "data": "Product"
  }, {
    "data": "Date",
    "render": function(data) {
      return moment(data).format('D/M/Y');
    }
  }],
  "orderFixed": [1, 'asc'],
  "order": [2, 'desc'],
  rowGroup: {
    startRender: null,
    endRender: function(rows, group) {
      return group + ' (' + rows.count() + ')';
    },
    dataSrc: 'Product'
  },
  "scrollCollapse": true,
  "search": {
    "caseInsensitive": true,
  },
  "ordering": false,
  "processing": true

});
```

Comment: You appear to have a syntax error; an extra `}` at the end of the `DataTable()` block. Check the console for more details and other errors

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks for your answer, but
i was wrong to copy the code, I don't have an extra }, i have edit ask now